# use of "how" and "In"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

My question is whether "How" can be preceded by "in" in a sentence and if the following instance where it has been used is grammatically correct.

> One of the major ways in which the current times are changing is **in
>   how** we communicate with each other.

Could you please explain.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*How* is one of those interrogative words that lets us ask a question, often with the auxiliary verb *do*:

> How **do** we communicate?

*How* asks about the manner of something (here, communicating). By dropping the *do*, we can transform this question into a clause that stands for the manner of that something:

> how we communicate

*Manner* is an abstract noun, and wherever we can use that noun in a sentence, we should be able to use the *how* clause in its place:

As the subject of a sentence:

> The manner of our communication is important.
>   How we communicate is important.

As the object of a transitive verb:

> I like the manner in which we communicate with each other.
>   I like how we communicate with each other.

As an objective complement:

> He showed us the proper manner of communication.
>   He showed us how to communicate properly.

And, as in your sentence, as the object of a preposition:

> The change is in the manner of our communication with each other.
>   The change is in how we communicate with each other.

The appearance of a particular preposition doesn't depend on the *how* clause, but rather on what word licenses that preposition, i.e., what preposition is idiomatic with the word.  *Change* can take *in*.  *Talk*, on the other hand, takes *about*.  So it's no surprise that we say

> Change **in** how we communicate.

and

> Talk **about** how we communicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you fill in an adequate noun you get an idea how such constructions come into being: in (the way) how we communicate with each other.

Before interrogative subclauses eg with "how/what/who etc" can occur a preposition as in

- a book about how alcohol is made - about (the way) how ...
- There has been much hand-wringing about how unprepared American students are
  for college - about (the degree) how ...
- a few more details on/about why your computer doesn't work - about the (question/problem) why ...